# Idol worship objects, what are they?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, art

The Torah talks about removing idol worship objects. Are we then just talking about statues? What about books, newspapers, pictures, paintings , maybe your house is designed in a form that goes back to a form of idol worship. How far does this go, what to Include and what to Exclude?

Comment: Note that churches are often built in the shape of a cross (at least on the inside).  I know of a synagogue that bought a church building and closed off the side rooms as offices

Comment: `The Torah talks about remowing idol worship objects` A reference to the relevant verse in the Torah would improve the question.

Comment: @mevaqesh So many Idol worship questions,I just did add that at the end

Comment: see [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50667/may-jews-create-sculpture-and-under-what-restrictions/72933?s=3|0.1024#72933) and [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73045/sculptures-of-animals-for-non-worship/73053?s=7|0.0727#73053) may be that you can find something interesting

Comment: @kouty "To design for beauty (art) is prohibited." Is that true?

Comment: @Aigle, excuse me, I have made this clearer now.

Comment: "whoever gets angry is as if he serves idols" (Zohar Korach daf 179, Rambam Deos 2:3). the idea is to deny in some way that God alone runs the world

Comment: @ray interesting

Answer (score 1):

> `books, newspapers, pictures, paintings`

If they are not in "bas relief" See [SA YD 141, 4](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5063), and some forms are allowed even in bas relief" (e.g. domestic animals) See [SA YD 141, 6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5064)

> `maybe your house is designed in a form that goes back to a form of idol worship`

If it is clear that the house is not similar to an idole, no problem. If the house is into a statue who is used as worship, there is a great problem. If the house has a form of cross (horizontally or vertically) not problem, this form is not for worship and is not royalty of idolatry.

There is a prohibition to make a house which is an exact reproduction of the Beth Hamikdash, see [SA YD 141, 8](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5065).

If the house was a church, but the people who was making worship inside leaved it, it is allowed too.

In [SA YD 245, 3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5075) A house or a stone of the house which was itself an object of worship are prohibited. A land itself may be prohibited in some conditions.

But these prohibitions concern cases very rare nowadays, almost in occidental world.

Comment: Well interesting,because Ikea furniture is designed to change Class differences,so both rich and poor has the same stuff(socialism).That is very political and then you do worship a mindset.As well These contemporary designs focus in modern houses (funkis house) ,might have to Do with E.Kant that said: art is not to glorify God.But is to be practical.Alle this to move us away from Something above us,there is only us and we are equal,that's everything.I would consider that an Idol

Comment: @Aigle eagle, adler, aquila... Ikea, socialism, E. Kant... I do not get it. I only tryied to answer your question.