# Is it prohibited to have a painting \ sculpure of a pig or any other non kosher animal in one's home?

Tags: halacha, non-kosher-species, art

Is it permitted, to have a piggy bank shape like, well a pig - for example?

Comment: leo, eagle, are not kosher and Yechezkel describes the chair of G.d as this. The king Salomon had a throne with sculptures on leos. See Yoma 54ab the large tosfot paragraph "keruvim".

Comment: I think Lubavitch have a thing where they refuse to allow pictures of tamei animals.

Comment: @user6591 I think Chaba"d  doesn't allow tamei animals as pets. I don't think they allow people to have dogs or cats.

Comment: @DanF: You can read the reasons and sources here: https://www.scribd.com/document/21015688/Non-Kosher-Animals-Toys  -- in short, it is tied to chinuch. From the moment they're born, when there is a choice, children should be exposed to pure things instead of  impure things. This does not apply to zoos, education purposes, etc. Read the article for more information

Comment: @Menachem (I assume you are Chaba"d, yourself?) B"N, I'll read it, soon. I gather that they are also careful not to have kids even play with "non-kosher" food toys such as plastic toy "pepperoni pizza".

Comment: @danf. Good question. I don't know what "official Chabad policy" is with that, but I do know parents who remove unambiguously non kosher food toys.

Answer (score 8):

First, the permission to paint or sculpt is not related to whether we can eat the animal. Some animals are treated more strictly: humans ,eagle, lion and bull. There are differences between representation in relief (3 dimensions) and flat (2 dimensions), and between whether there is a possibility that idolatry might be involved or not e.g. when the representation is educative.

There are nuances between rishonim regarding some cases.One of the important Tosfot is in Yoma 54ab.

But anyway, the criterion of Kashrut is not mentioned in halacha. For instance, the King Solomon had a throne with sculptures of lions  as written in Melachim I. Lion is not Kosher.

See 
 [May Jews create sculpture, and under what restrictions?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50667/may-jews-create-sculpture-and-under-what-restrictions/72933#72933)
and [Sculptures of Animals for non-worship](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73045/sculptures-of-animals-for-non-worship/73053#73053)